# Bitbucket Pipieline won't authenticate using Private Key

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using Bitbucket's pipeline feature that stores the private & public key on the container.

When I try to ssh into a remote machine (that already stores the public key in the `authorized_keys` file) I get the following error:

```
debug2: key: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What did I miss in this flow?

Comment: Did you find a solution after all? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Just added an answer, in other projects i used laravel forge with a simple `wget` to trigger the deployment

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    stage:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Staging
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
              - echo "Deploying to Staging"
              - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.2
                variables:
                  SSH_USER: 'ubuntu'
                  SERVER: '<server-ip-here>'
                  COMMAND: 'sudo /opt/scripts/pull-code.sh' 
              - echo "Finished Deploying"
      - step:
          name: E2E Tests
          image: cypress/included:10.11.0
          script:
            - npm install cypress-real-events@^1.7.1
            - cypress run --record --key <cypress-key-here>
```

Comment: It turns out I needed to include an image in all steps or an image overall